# Where do I put my list of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of postcodes of 'areas covered'. When a user enters their postcode I want to compare that postcode to the list of areas covered, and then tell the user whether the area is covered or not.

I'm struggling to get my head around the best place to store my list of post codes, would it simply be a 'post_code' model with just one column?

Comment: That depends on how you want to store, access and change the data. It could be a ruby constant in code, it could be a single model, it could be a complex cross-referenced thing, ... Only you known your requirements. If a simple model does what you want, sure go ahead. If not, use something different.

Comment: as @HolgerJust says we don't know your other reqs.  Do you have other information about the postcodes stored, such as shipping rates, etc.. Or do you need to link this info to other models in your application. Is it a big list does it change often, etc...

Comment: Currently I have a 'user' model and a supplier 'model'.  When a supplier has a postcode on their profile page which matches the users postcode enquiry the postcode on the 'postcode' model will be true. The list of postcodes will not change.

Comment: for non-changing set of values I in same situation chose to add a yml file to lib and parse it with custom method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one model should fit fine. Add an index on `postcode` for faster search, also you may want some field like `is_active` to prevent frequent addition/deletion, if list changes frequently